# Set margin in btn-group in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How can I add top margin and margin in general in btn-group bootstrap. What class I should add and where? Thanks in advance

How can I add top margin and margin in general in btn-group bootstrap. What class I should add and where? Thanks in advance

[btn-group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnMqD.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Golden Titles</title>

    <meta name="description" content="Source code">
    <meta name="author" content="Rahman">

    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="btn-group pull-right">

                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                    Sign in
                </button> 
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                    My Account
                </button> 
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                    Help
                </button> 

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. add new css file (customized-bootstrap.css)
2. append below code to this file:

   ```
   .btn-group button {
       top-margin: 1em !important;
   }
   ```
3. add this file after bootstrap file in layout page

   ```
   <link href="../../dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="../css/customized-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
   ```